# Why 2 requests are sent from Java Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have created one HTTP Post request with Basic authentication using **httpclient (*org.apache.httpcomponents)***.

```
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user","pass"));

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().
                setConnectTimeout(2000).
                setSocketTimeout(2000).
                build();
       try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().
                setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).
                setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).
                build()) {
            
            String reqString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj); // here obj is a Java class of request payload
            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(reqString);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); // server url where double requests are going
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(params);    

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {

                final String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                if (200 == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    
                } 
            }
        }
```

When **CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)** is executed 2 request went to the server, First one without Basic Authorizatin in header and 2nd one with Basic Authorizatin in header. What is the reason for this?

I dig down into the **httpclient-4.5.3** library and found that actual point of double request generation is ***org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec***. On that class **execute** method contains a for loop which is actually executed 2 times. I am giving that for loop below...

```
    for (int execCount = 1;; execCount++) {

            if (execCount > 1 && !RequestEntityProxy.isRepeatable(request)) {
                throw new NonRepeatableRequestException("Cannot retry request " +
                        "with a non-repeatable request entity.");
            }

            if (execAware != null && execAware.isAborted()) {
                throw new RequestAbortedException("Request aborted");
            }

            if (!managedConn.isOpen()) {
                this.log.debug("Opening connection " + route);
                try {
                    establishRoute(proxyAuthState, managedConn, route, request, context);
                } catch (final TunnelRefusedException ex) {
                    if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        this.log.debug(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    response = ex.getResponse();
                    break;
                }
            }
            final int timeout = config.getSocketTimeout();
            if (timeout >= 0) {
                managedConn.setSocketTimeout(timeout);
            }

            if (execAware != null && execAware.isAborted()) {
                throw new RequestAbortedException("Request aborted");
            }

            if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.log.debug("Executing request " + request.getRequestLine());
            }

            if (!request.containsHeader(AUTH.WWW_AUTH_RESP)) {
                if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    this.log.debug("Target auth state: " + targetAuthState.getState());
                }
                this.authenticator.generateAuthResponse(request, targetAuthState, context);
            }
            if (!request.containsHeader(AUTH.PROXY_AUTH_RESP) && !route.isTunnelled()) {
                if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    this.log.debug("Proxy auth state: " + proxyAuthState.getState());
                }
                this.authenticator.generateAuthResponse(request, proxyAuthState, context);
            }

            response = requestExecutor.execute(request, managedConn, context);

            // The connection is in or can be brought to a re-usable state.
            if (reuseStrategy.keepAlive(response, context)) {
                // Set the idle duration of this connection
                final long duration = keepAliveStrategy.getKeepAliveDuration(response, context);
                if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    final String s;
                    if (duration > 0) {
                        s = "for " + duration + " " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
                    } else {
                        s = "indefinitely";
                    }
                    this.log.debug("Connection can be kept alive " + s);
                }
                connHolder.setValidFor(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                connHolder.markReusable();
            } else {
                connHolder.markNonReusable();
            }

            if (needAuthentication(
                    targetAuthState, proxyAuthState, route, response, context)) {
                // Make sure the response body is fully consumed, if present
                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (connHolder.isReusable()) {
                    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                } else {
                    managedConn.close();
                    if (proxyAuthState.getState() == AuthProtocolState.SUCCESS
                            && proxyAuthState.getAuthScheme() != null
                            && proxyAuthState.getAuthScheme().isConnectionBased()) {
                        this.log.debug("Resetting proxy auth state");
                        proxyAuthState.reset();
                    }
                    if (targetAuthState.getState() == AuthProtocolState.SUCCESS
                            && targetAuthState.getAuthScheme() != null
                            && targetAuthState.getAuthScheme().isConnectionBased()) {
                        this.log.debug("Resetting target auth state");
                        targetAuthState.reset();
                    }
                }
                // discard previous auth headers
                final HttpRequest original = request.getOriginal();
                if (!original.containsHeader(AUTH.WWW_AUTH_RESP)) {
                    request.removeHeaders(AUTH.WWW_AUTH_RESP);
                }
                if (!original.containsHeader(AUTH.PROXY_AUTH_RESP)) {
                    request.removeHeaders(AUTH.PROXY_AUTH_RESP);
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Can any one give me some idea why the first request does not contain any basic Authorization in header but the second one contains that?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging further within the **httpclient-4.5.3** library, I found that, there is two states (targetAuthState, proxyAuthState) there. Initially both of the states have value **UNCHALLEGED**.

So the library at first send a request without any *Authorization* value in header to check if any authentication scheme is required or not. If the returned value is **4XX**, then targetAuthState value is changed to **CHALLEGED**. And this time library send request with *Authorization* value in header.

But if any one do not want this behavior, in that case basic Authorization have to be set directly without using **CredentialsProvider**.

> byte[] credentials = Base64.encodeBase64(("user" + ":" + "pass").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
> httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(credentials, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

The complete code will be like follwoing.

```
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().
            setConnectTimeout(2000).
            setSocketTimeout(2000).
            build();
   try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().
            setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).
            build()) {
        
        String reqString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj); // here obj is a Java class of request payload
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(reqString);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); // server url where double requests are going
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        byte[] credentials = Base64.encodeBase64(("user" + ":" + "pass").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(credentials, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        httpPost.setEntity(params);    

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {

            final String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            if (200 == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                
            } 
        }
    }
```